# How to extract FactoryGirl traits in a separate file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, factory-bot

I have a bunch of factories that share a common trait:

```
trait :with_images do
  after(:create) do |resource|
    resource.images << FactoryGirl.create(:image, imageable: resource)
    resource.enabled = true
    resource.save
  end
end
```

I would like to extract it in a separate file but not 100% sure how to arrange it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits can be defined globally, so then you can use them in another factory you like. You could create a new file inside **spec/factories**, like, **spec/factories/traits.rb** or something:

And define your global traits:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  trait :complete do
    complete false
  end
end
```

And then you would have in another file, say **spec/factories/user.rb**, a different factory using this trait:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    complete
  end
end
```

I'm just not sure if that's a good idea, I mean, I think it should be visible right away that a trait is kind of a complement of a given factory. It is very clean, but not so readable.